# performance between converted and loaded file with pyside

Tags: python, pyside, benchmarking

I saw that there are 2 ways for use the ui file with pyside. It's possible to convert or to load file. What is the best performance between this 2 solutions ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should run some tests to find out

Answer (score 0):

Conversion processes the ui file *once* and creates a static module. Loading the ui file at runtime processes it *every time* the application is run. So obviously any difference in performance is going to be roughly equal to the overhead of processing the ui file.

Having said that, runtime performance is probably not a good reason for choosing between them. Most people prefer one over the other simply because it provides a better fit for their development process.